# Simplify my JQuery Mess

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Answer, slightly modified from marked answer:**

```
var eoc = "easeOutCirc",mNSS = 'metrsoNavSpanSelected';

$('.metroNavSpan').click(function(){
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('.content-box').eq(ind).prevAll().animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,eoc);
    $('.content-box').eq(ind).nextAll().andSelf().animate({marginLeft: 0},750,eoc);
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: (-65*ind)},1550,eoc);
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass(mNSS);
    $(this).addClass(mNSS);
});
```

Changes: Spelling on eastOutCirc was fixed :)

background postion animation changed from -= (65*ind) to just (-65*ind). Didn't want the changes to be cumulitive, meaning panel one should be 0,0; panel two should be -65,0 always. -= was accumulating clicks so that going back and forth between panel 4 and 5 would end up with very large - numbers.

nextAll and prevAll were separated, as keeping them in the same line was always snapping panels back to panel 1 after animation.

**Original Question:**

I have a series of panels I'm animating in a Metro style for a website. The problem is, I'm not seeing a good way to do the below in fewer lines of code. How can I do something like this in a more compact elegant fashion?

```
$('#metroNow').click(function() {
    $("#c1").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c2").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c3").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c4").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c5").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: 0}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    $('#metroNow').addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
});
$('#metroPeople').click(function() {
    $("#c1").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c2").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c3").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c4").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c5").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: -65}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    $('#metroPeople').addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
});
$('#metroInfopedia').click(function() {
    $("#c1").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c2").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c3").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c4").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c5").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: -130}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    $('#metroInfopedia').addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
});
$('#metroVideos').click(function() {
    $("#c1").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750, "easeOutCirc");
    $("#c2").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c3").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c4").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c5").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: -195}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    $('#metroVideos').addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
});
$('#metroAbout').click(function() {
    $("#c1").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c2").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c3").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c4").animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $("#c5").animate({marginLeft: 0},750,"easeOutCirc");
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: -260}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    $('#metroAbout').addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
});
```

Comment: You should try [HERE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
***As I could not test the code the OP made great working changes on this one. Look at the Question to find the real working answer!***

Here: your 50 liner into 9 lines of code.

If your #c1, #c2.. .and so on have a  same parent 
add to all of them a class '.el'  Ex: `<div id="c2" class="el"></div>`

```
var eoc = "easeOutCirc",
    mNSS = 'metrsoNavSpanSelected';

$('.metroNavSpan').click(function(){
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('.el').eq(ind).prevAll().animate({marginLeft: -1040},750,eoc).nextAll().andSelf().animate({marginLeft: 0},750,eoc);
    $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: '-='+(65*ind) },1550,eoc);
    $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass(mNSS);
    $(this).addClass(mNSS);
});
```

Comment: This almost works and is the most elegent solution. The only issue is, it snaps right back into position. Gonna see if I can fix it.

Comment: Marked yours answer, but corrected a few things. See my post for corrections.

Comment: Thanks Wesley! I misspelled the "easeOutCirc" While fast-typing! Glad you find the typo and errors in my code (I could not test it so I wrote it from my mind) and you made it work! Hura!

Answer (score 8):

Use comma for selector who have the same animate properties. For Example:  $("#c1, #c2, #c3, ...")

Comment: Even better do var myObj = $("#c1, #c2, #c3,"). Then do myObj.animate()

Comment: That helps reduce a LOT of code, but I'm not sure it's the whole puzzle. Gonna try a few things out, but this is VERY helpful. Upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what others have said, make 1 function for what you are trying to do, then call that with different arguments:

```
var totalCTags = 5
function initMetroLink(link, index) {
    $(link).click(function() {
        for (var i=1; i<=totalCTags; ++i) {
            var margin = (index<=i ? -1040 : 0);
            $("#c"+i).animate({marginLeft: margin}, 750, "easeOutCirc");
        }
        var fakePosition = index * -65;
        $('#fake').animate({backgroundPosition: fakePosition}, 1550, "easeOutCirc");
        $('.metroNavSpan').removeClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
        $(link).addClass('metroNavSpanSelected');
    });
}

initMetroLink("#metroNow", 0);
initMetroLink("#metroPeople", 1);
initMetroLink("#metroInfopedia", 2);
initMetroLink("#metroVideos", 3);
initMetroLink("#metroAbout", 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to organize, these all seem to be doing the same thing... why not name them a little differently, or add classes, and just:

```
function animateMyDivs(obj, marginLeft, val, animType){
    obj.animate({marginLeft: marginLeft},val,animType);
}
```

After loading...

```
$('[id*="divIDStartsWith"]').each(function () {
    $(this).bind('click',function(){
        animateMyDivs($(this), -1400, 750, 'easeOutCirc');
    })
})
```

Any time you are doing two of something, it's cleaner to add it to a function (or even a plugin), plus, you can reuse it!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
var eoc = "easeOutCirc",
mNSS = "metrsoNavSpanSelected";
$(".metroNavSpan")
.click(function () {
var a = $(this)
    .index();
$(".content-box")
    .eq(a)
    .prevAll()
    .animate({
    marginLeft: -1040
}, 750, eoc), $(".content-box")
    .eq(a)
    .nextAll()
    .andSelf()
    .animate({
    marginLeft: 0
}, 750, eoc), $("#fake")
    .animate({
    backgroundPosition: -65 * a
}, 1550, eoc), $(".metroNavSpan")
    .removeClass(mNSS), $(this)
    .addClass(mNSS)
})
```